# Warning - Critical Dependency when dynamically loading csv

Tags: javascript, webpack, import

I'm trying to use webpack to load a .csv data set when the user clicks on it. This is done in the callback to a click even that's been configured with Vue, so I've got something like this:

```
onClick : function(clickData){
  var path = '../data/' + clickData.path;
  var onLoad = function(loadedCsv){
     console.log(loadedCsv);
  };
  import(path).then(onLoad);
}
```

When I compile this with webpack, I get the error "68:4-16 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression". Additionally, the data set fails to load.

I've also found the following:

- I get the same warning/problem whether I use the "import" or the "require" syntax
- I can import my .csv if I add it in the initial "require" statement as a static path (i.e. "../data/myCsv.csv"), and it imports fine with the loader I've set up.

My goal is to only import the data sets I want. I'm populating a Vue component using a JSON describing all of my data, so I need to be passing the data sets in to my import statement as variables, rather than hard coding the paths. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the local variable `path` and change your import statement to `import('../data/' + file + '.csv')`. This way webpack will be able to resolve the context and create a context module containing a map of csv files to module Ids.